# Published or released? [This book was "released in 1890" or this book was "published .." ?]

Tags: meaning, verbs

What's the difference in meaning between publishing a book and releasing a book?

Answer (score 2):

Both options can be used, see [publish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/publish) and [release](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/release) dictionary definitions.

Even though the word **publish** might just have become too old-fashioned for nowadays consumers and the use of the word **release** is on the increase, for books case, I’d rather use **publish**

If we were talking about a movie, music CD, or software then the word **release** would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, to the effect of the opposite of the other answer here, is *no.* To elaborate, the synonyms listed by Google come daringly close to *released*:

> [make known, make public, publicize, bring to public notice/attention, announce, report, declare, post, communicate, impart, broadcast, transmit, issue, put out, distribute, spread, promulgate, propagandize, disseminate, circulate, air, blazon, herald, proclaim; disclose, reveal, divulge, leak](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=synonyms%20for%20publish)

I'm not convinced that either would sound odd in that use case, but one point I ought to mention is that *publishing* can refer to the entire process of publishing-- the paperwork and all those sorts of things.

Comment: this point is important and that what I was asking about